# Java Regular Expression Confusion

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular expression:

```
^[!.@] (update)
```

It will match `!update` but will not match if anything follows it.

For example `!update hat` will not match. There is a large amount of possibilities that could follow the `!update` and I want it to match just that part regardless of what follows it in the string.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you match? `String#matches(regex)`? If so, either append `.*` or use `Pattern` and `Matcher` (especially the `find()` method) directly.

Comment: Put something that matches anything after the regex. It also matters how you're *using* the regex, which you don't show.

Comment: So you want to have a regex, which matches just '!update', but nothing behind it?

Comment: Using the regex engine in my mind, that regex will *not* match `!update` since there's no space after the exclamation mark.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `^[!.@] (update).*`?

Comment: Or something like `^([!.@]update)`? I understood it the way he does NOT want to match it anything else than 'update' and one character before it.

Comment: @MartinBeseda "I want it to match just that part regardless of what follows it" sounds like `!update hat` should match as well. The OP probably just wants to get the group that would contain the string "update".

Comment: @user3217010 provide some valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Edit your question to include example input (2 or 3 different lines), the output you want from each line of input and the Java code where you use the RegEx and you will be sure to get some good help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[!.@](update )(.*)$
```

Seems to fit your requirements.